# Why is Apache Solr not Returning any Results?

Tags: search, solr

After creating a Solr core named "test", I loaded in an XML file using the following:
`bin\solr.cmd create -c test`
`java -jar -Dc=test -Dauto example\exampledocs\post.jar C:\Example\data.xml`

Here are the contents of the file, data.xml.

**data.xml**

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="field_name_1">Value One</field>
        <field name="field_name_2">Value Two</field>
        <field name="field_name_3">Value Three</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="field_name_1">Value Four</field>
        <field name="field_name_2">Value Five</field>
        <field name="field_name_3">Value Six</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="field_name_1">Value Seven</field>
        <field name="field_name_2">Value Eight</field>
        <field name="field_name_3">Value Nine</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

The following query does not return a result. Why is Solr not returning anything for this query?
`http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=Value`

**Result:**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"Value"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Comment: Does querying for `*:*` give you anything? Does querying for `field-name-1:Value` give you anything? You should also use a different field name: _Field names should consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit._ `-` has special meaning in the query syntax.

Comment: Changed the contents of data.xml to use underscores. Also added two more documents. `*:*` returns all of the documents, and `field_name_1:One` returns only the first document.

Comment: In that case you want to use the edismax handler - add `defType=edismax&qf=field_name_1 field_name_2 field_name_3` to your query to use a more natural search query (i.e. just `Value`) and a list of fields to search.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but isn't this not optimal? In the techproducts examples you can search any string and it will search all of the fields in all of the documents. What do I need to change so that any string can be searched without needing to include field names in the query?

Comment: You can't - but you can add a `copyField` rule that copies everything into one common field - for example a field named `_text_`, `search` or `content`, then search against that field. This is what the `techproducts` example does in the background (and then sets the `_text_` field as the default search field). This is fine for many cases. Common issues are that it doesn't allow you to process content in the fields differently or apply different weights based on the content (i.e. you can't weigh hits in title and description differently).